# Aguardar resposta do ajax antes de seguir no loop

Tags: javascript, promises

Como eu poderia fazer o seguinte código funcionar?
Na pagina sleep.php tenho 2 segundos de espera somente para o teste.
Preciso que o próximo `for` seja executado somente
após a execução completa da função `corrige`.

Tentei usar "promises" mas não consigo entender como usar em cada elemento do `for`.

```
$(".start").on('click',function(e){            
 var anexo = document.getElementsByClassName('anexos');            
 for (var i = 0; i < anexo.length; ++i) {
  /* aqui eu quero que cada execução do FOR 
   * seja executada somente após o término
   * da função "corrige"...
  */     
  corrige(anexo[i]);
 }            
});

function corrige(func){
 $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',                    
  url: 'sleep.php',
  dataType: 'json'
 });    
}
```

Comment: Você quer "pausar" o loop a cada iteração, é isso? Explique melhor o que você está tentando fazer. O que vai acontecer dentro do loop?

Comment: Não seria pausar... e sim esperar a função "corrige" ser finalizada e somente após isso, continuar o loop... 

dentro do FOR vai a função "corrige", esqueci de colocar lá...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sem utilizar es8, da para pensar em recursividade:

```
$(".start").on('click',function(e){            
 var anexo = document.getElementsByClassName('anexos');    
 corrigir(anexos);       
});

function corrigir(anexos) {
 corrige(anexos, 0, anexos.length - 1);
}

function corrige(anexos, i, max){
    if(i <= max) {
      console.log('atual: ', anexos[i]);
       $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',                    
        url: 'sleep.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          corrige(anexos, ++i, max);
        }
      });  
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito a solução com recursividade, muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Acho que essa minha resposta é mais uma curiosidade do que útil na prática, devido a problemas de compatibilidade (não vai funcionar no IE nem em browsers antigos).

```
function ajaxPromise(indice) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    $.post('/echo/html/', {html:'server response ' + indice}).then(resolve);
  });
}

async function asyncLoop() {
  for(let i=0; i<10; i++) {
    var rsp = ajaxPromise(i);
    console.log('after ajax', i,  await rsp);
  }
}

asyncLoop();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7cs3buo9/

Comment: Seria interessante se justificassem o downvote, pois não funcionar em browser obsoletos não é mais um grande problema.